# Azure Function Publish Fails to Specific Subscription From Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, publish, visual-studio-2019

I have a working published function, that has been published multiple times for the past 3 months from VS, that *now* when I try to now publish in VS2019 or VS2017 **it fails**. Publishing into a *new function* (in the same subscription), instead of updating **fails** too; but the new function is visible in Azure/resource group.

[image]

**It actually deletes the files up there**, so that what was there...is now gone with these two files in its place:

[image]

The text file is "Run From Package Initialization failed."

I tried restting and pulling down a new profile with the same failure:

[image]

I have tried zip publishing, non-zip etc. I changed the environment variable `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` from 1 to zero.

**Thoughts?**

---

**I can publish the function to another subscription with no issues**.

---

**Diagnostic Log File From C Drive**

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Publishing failed.    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__202.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---
>
> System.Exception: Publishing failed.

---

I also posted this on the Azure/AzureFunction GitHub issue section:

[Azure Function Publish Fails to Specific Subscription From Visual Studio](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1318)

Comment: To clarify, same VS version and same VS project, publish to one function app works while doing the same to another function app always fails, correct?  If so, please share the function app names of success and fail ones and the respective UTC time of the publish - we can look from our end.

Comment: Same function. Different versions of Visual Studio. Works if its published to a different azure subscription. Fails if published to original (first) azure subscription.

Comment: Did you try using the Azure CLI to push the function? Maybe you will get a better error message... e.g. https://markheath.net/post/deploying-azure-functions-with-azure-cli

Answer (score 1):

I test in my site and can reproduce you problem.

When I republish azure function it will get publish failed. However when I recreate a new function on portal and publish again, it works well.

So, you could refer the following steps to troubleshoot.

1.[Remove Profile](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/294#issuecomment-473008144) and create a new profile.(choose run from package file)

2.Set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` or you could try to remove this tag.

Comment: Any update now? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Comment: I have reset the publish profile and the run package to 0. Unfortunately Microsoft is advising me to delete the whole placeholder in Azure and start over.

Comment: Have you refer to this [solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316029/azure-web-deploy-publish-failed.html)?

Comment: It suggests to download a new published profile which I have done.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately contacted Microsoft Support and burned a support ticket. I ended up receiving two separate pieces of advice which helped me *work around* the problem and get back to working.

**Advice #1**

- Either delete the existing Function Holder (*the function itself*) in Azure and republish/publish anew.

**Advice #2**

- Only publish using Zip Deploy.
- Create new publish profile in Visual Studio and publish using the Zip deploy; web deploy (in VS 2017/2019) has issues. (*What those **issues** are were not detailed to me*)

---

To be clear I ended up publishing to a new function and ignoring the old function. But a week later, publishing to it ended up getting the same issue, until I did advice #2.

Nothing seemed to work for the original function, no matter how I published to it.

I am not marking this as an answer, for it still feels like a work around. My function is running and updated, but it still feels like a publish failure is just around the corner. *IMHO*